# Best practice for reading styles of element JSDOM

Tags: javascript, html, testing, jsdom

To get style attributes from an element using JSDOM, I use the following:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element)
```

It's the only example I've found. Using `element.style.someAttribute` does not seem to return anything.

Is usinging `getComputedStyle` the best way to find the values of attributes?

ty!

Comment: Short answer, **Yes**. *Using element.style.someAttribute does not seem to return anything* because you have not set those attribute to element. You are setting it using CSS.

Comment: The style object has history, the values of its various attributes are dependent on how they are set and don't necessarily match the  computed value, hence the introduction of *getComputedStyle*. See MDN: [*HTMLElement.style*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). Also [*other questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+getcomputedstyle+element.style).

Comment: Rajesh is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.style` does only reflect the content of the `style` attribute of the HTML element. It does not take into account the real style which can be set with class styles, id styles, etc.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style
(Emphasis mine)

> The HTMLElement.style property is used to get as well as set the **inline** style of an element. When getting, it returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object that contains a list of all styles properties for that element with values assigned for the attributes that are defined in the element's **inline** style attribute.

That means:

```js
mySpan = document.getElementById('my-span')
console.info('element.style')
console.info('color', mySpan.style.color)
console.info('font-weight', mySpan.style.fontWeight)
console.info('getComputedStyle')
console.info('color', window.getComputedStyle(mySpan).color)
console.info('font-weight', window.getComputedStyle(mySpan).fontWeight)
```

```css
#my-span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span id="my-span" style="color: red;">This is red and bold</span>
```